# Gmail contextual gadget deployment

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Seems that UI was changed once again and I cannot deploy "Hello world" Gmail Contextual Gadget following the steps provided by Joc ([Gmail contextual gadget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926796/gmail-contextual-gadget)):

- There are no "Allow individual install" on the step #7
- I also cannot find "Test installation flow" (step #10)
- The gadget is not listed in the Marketplace list (step #11)

Could you please assist me?

Comment: I just checked the Marketplace SDK configuration page of my projects and I can see everything. are you still having the issue?

Answer (score 0):

- In `google apps marketplace sdk` API, in tab `configure`, after `Application info` section, there is a checkbox `Enable individual install`
- After you save changes at the bottom of this page there is a button `Test installation flow` at the top of the page. I admit, sometimes it doesn't appear to me.
- the Marketplace list I can't reach at the current time. I don't know how to be an administrator or how to make a free trial domain (although it's written in `apps.google.com`)