# Gmail contextual gadgets

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am trying to create a contextual gadget for gmail.
I followed the documentation exactly but not able to create a working version.

However, I created a gadget by making some modifications and I got it working on the main window of GMail.
But when I add the extractors like HelloWorld, by uncommenting the Require tag, it is not working.

This file is hosted in http://ripplesonline.in/gadget.working.xml and I selected all items in the scope.

Here is the gadget xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="Hello World" description="Matches and echoes 'Hello World' string in emails" >  
    <!--
    <Require feature="google.contentmatch">
      <Param name="extractors">
        google.com:HelloWorld,google.com:SenderEmailExtractor
      </Param>
    </Require>
    -->
  </ModulePrefs>

  <Content type="html">
     <![CDATA[ 
        <script>
            function justAnAlert(){
                console.log("just a test");
                debugger
                alert("just a test");
            }
            gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(justAnAlert);

        </script>
       Hello, world!
     ]]>
  </Content> 

</Module>
```

Thanks

Comment: I am trying for 1 week now, and can't make this works correctly! I followed the documentation, and this steps [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926796/gmail-contextual-gadget) , but the gadget never shows up in the mail. However, it's in the App's list (installed using the button "Test Instalation flow"). What am I missing? Your gadget works? Can you PLEASE help me?

Comment: I couldn't get it work as I expected. I am now using chrome extensions instead.